# Octave and warning "ARPACK library found, but does not seem to work properly; disabling eigs function"

Tags: octave, configure, m4, arpack

#### Situation

I work with Ubuntu 14.04. I am building GNU Octave 4.2.1 from source with GNU 6.3.0. This version of Octave is quite new, but I see the issue arising also when trying to compile older Octave releases (down to 3.8.1).

I configure the build of Octave with

```
${sourcedir}/configure --prefix=/opt/octave/4.2.1 \
--with-java-homedir=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java \
--with-java-libdir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

#### Issue

The compilation is successful but the undesired warning shows up

```
configure: WARNING: ARPACK library found, but does not seem to work properly; disabling eigs function
```

I would rather like to have the eigs() function in place.

#### Information

I have built ARPACK-ng myself with the same compiler. All tests in the test suite (`make check`) are passed. The environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` point to the ARPACK library directory as intended. The configure file of Octave recognizes that location correctly, as seen before.

Besides, I get the same message if I compile Octave in another computer where ARPACK is installed natively (`libarpack2` and `libarpack2-dev` version 3.1.5-2). It does not change a thing if I also install the related extra libraries `libarpack++2c2a` and `libarpack++2-dev` using the package repository. So the issue appears to be independent of the origin of the ARPACK files.

The part of the `configure.ac` file of Octave that throws this error is

```
### Check for ARPACK library.

save_LIBS="$LIBS"
LIBS="$LAPACK_LIBS $BLAS_LIBS $FLIBS $LIBS"
OCTAVE_CHECK_LIB([arpack], ARPACK,
[ARPACK not found.  The eigs function will be disabled.],
[],
[dseupd],
[Fortran 77], [don't use the ARPACK library, disable eigs function],
[warn_arpack=
OCTAVE_CHECK_LIB_ARPACK_OK(
[AC_DEFINE(HAVE_ARPACK, 1, [Define to 1 if ARPACK is available.])],
[warn_arpack="ARPACK library found, but does not seem to work properly; disabling eigs function"])])
LIBS="$save_LIBS"
```

The farthest I go in tracing back the issue is that the subroutine `OCTAVE_CHECK_LIB_ARPACK_OK` issuing the warning lives in the file `${octave_source}/m4/acinclude.m4`. It is written in [m4 language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)), which I don't know

#### Question

Is it possible to understand why ARPACK 'does not seem to work properly'?

Is there any workaround for this?

Is this a false alarm or a bug?

Comment: I assume this `configure` is an autotools-style `configure`. Did you check `config.log`?

Comment: @uzsolt Yes it is and yes I had. The config.log that exits with status 0 and is little bothered (we are dealing with warnings, after all). I shall add that in the meantime, after a little head-banging, I isolated the cause of the issue in the gcc compiler, which had been built from source as well. I still have to formulate the issue properly, will ask in a separate post and come back with my solution.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this problem. I am experiencing the same issue on CentOS 6.6

Comment: @irritable_phd_syndrom My evidence is that the arpack libraries are not included if I compile Octave with my own gcc passing CC or CXX as environment variables to the configure command for Octave. Rather, if I only use my own gcc for CPP and/or FC/F77, then arpack is included. Likewise, if I use the native gcc, arpack is included. In sum, the problem seems to be caused, at least, by some dislike for my own C and C++, but I haven't investigated this further. Hope this helps a bit.